# How to run mapnik python on OSX?

Tags: python

I just installed mapnik with "brew install mapnik" on OSX Lion. I tried running:

"import mapnik" after opened the system python terminal with the command "python" and I get a

"ImportError: No module named mapnik"

It seems simple here:
https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MacInstallation_Homebrew

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

one of the last line in the installation process:

"For non-homebrew Python, you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:

`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`"

so just place this text in ~/.bash_profile